# Add "sender/from" line to postal mailing labels

Tags: address-labels

I like to add a "from" line at the mailing label so we can use cheaper blank envelopes and am looking for the location and filename of the stylesheet of the labels. If I do it in Administer - Localization - Address Settings the font for the sender is to big.

Like:

consigner/sender | xystreet 12 | zip town

---

recipient Name

Street

ZIP town

I have checked documentation but could only found how to add physical formats so far. Thank you for your tipps!

SECOND is there a way to define a start position, having a sheet that is patially used? e.g. start at label 5 or start at row2, label 2

Comment: Please only include a single question in each question. That restriction in StackExchange is what makes it possible to accurately vote on which answers are good.

Answer (score 4):

My solution for Question 1:

I create labels with the recipients in CiviCRM and save it. Than i create a label-sheet with the same format in libre-office only with the "from"-line and safe it as pdf. then i use "pdf chain" (for linux) to merge this two files together. in "pdf chain" it called "backround/stamp". so it "stamps the "from"-pdf as often as needed in to the pdf from CiviCRM.

Comment: Very helpful. Obviously different variants for different environments. I produced the background pdf in Word and the used Adobe Acrobat to add it to the pdf from CiviCRM. Very easy.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to pdfchain, this can easily be done using pdftk:

> pdftk MailingLabels_CiviCRM.pdf multistamp pdfstamp.pdf output out.pdf

The only thing you need, is a pdf file (maybe created using LibreOffice) that can be used as the "stamp" for the whole page of mailing labels.